# ModuleNotFoundError when importing my package, but not when running it alone

Tags: python-3.x, package, importerror, python-poetry

I'm trying to create a python package, and I have have trouble with the imports. My code works as expected when running it, but when I install the package using poetry and import it in another script, I have a ModuleNotFoundError.

My file structure is the following :

```
git_repo
|  myapp
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--mainscript.py
|  |--library
|  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |--module.py
```

My file `mainscript.py` imports the `module.py` because there are some utility functions :
`from library import module`

When I execute the mainscript, no problem. However, when installing `myapp` using `poetry install` and trying to import it in a python shell :

```py
> python

>>> import myapp.mainscript

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\path\to\mainscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    from library import module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'
```

Is there a mechanic I don't understand with the imports ? Do I have to write something in the `__init__.py` files ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution to my own problem.

As J_H suggested, I tried relative imports. This worked when installing my package and using it. But I encountered `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when running my mainscript.

The solution was to use absolute imports. Now this works both when installing the package and running the mainscript.

```py
# mainscript.py
from myapp.library import module
```

I also added some imports in the `__init__.py` files in order to ease the use of my package when installed :

```py
# myapp/__init__.py
from . import library
from .mainscript import mainClass
```

This allows me to do `a = myapp.mainClass()` instead of `a = myapp.mainscript.mainClass()`

Answer (score 2):

> there are some utility functions:
> `from library import module`

You want:

```
from .library import module
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

https://realpython.com/python-import/#absolute-and-relative-imports

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, this does not work. When I make your change and run my script, I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` and when I run it with `python -m` I get `Relative module names not supported`. I will keep digging this way though

Comment: Yes, I understand. What matters is _how_ you invoke the program. You must `cd ..` so you're up at the git_repo level. Then "myapp" and "myapp.library" will be visible to the interpreter. If you start too far down, the interpreter doesn't see that "myapp" is a module. Remember that `.` is shorthand for `myapp`, here. Using `-m myapp` is a fine alternative, but the same restriction applies to it, as well, so your starting directory matters. (You might find it convenient to write a brief Bourne script that invokes correctly, to save typing. Or a `make` target.) Also, `export PYTHONPATH=.` helps.